# Text Replacement -- Pattern is a set list of strings [r]

Tags: r, apply, code-cleanup, stringr, text-manipulation

I have a string variable in a large data set that I want to cleanse based on a set list of strings. ex. pattern <- c("dog","cat") but my list will be about 400 elements long.

**vector_to_clean == a**

```
black Dog
white dOG
doggie
black CAT
thatdamcat
```

Then I want to apply a function to yield

**new**

```
dog
dog
dog
cat
cat
```

I have tried str_extract, grep, grepl etc.. Since I can pick a pattern based on one string at a time. I think what I want is to use dapply with one of these text cleansing functions. Unfortunately, I'm stuck. Below is my latest attempt. Thank you for your help!

```
new <- vector()

lapply(pattern, function(x){
  where<- grep(x,a,value = FALSE, ignore.case = TRUE)
  new[where]<-x
  })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We `paste` the 'pattern' vector together to create a single string, use that to extract the words from 'vec1' after we change it to lower case (`tolower(vec1)`).

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(tolower(vec1), paste(pattern, collapse='|'))
#[1] "dog" "dog" "dog" "cat" "cat"
```

#### data

```
pattern <- c("dog","cat") 
vec1 <- c('black Dog', 'white dOG', 'doggie','black CAT', 'thatdamcat')
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way using base R is:

```
#data
vec <- c('black Dog', 'white dOG', 'doggie','black CAT','thatdamcat')

#regexpr finds the locations of cat and dog ignoring the cases
a <- regexpr( 'dog|cat', vec, ignore.case=TRUE )

#regmatches returns the above locations from vec (here we use tolower in order 
#to convert to lowercase)
regmatches(tolower(vec), a)
[1] "dog" "dog" "dog" "cat" "cat"
```

Comment: I tried this one out too and it works, but it isn't quite what I want because I also have 'bird' in my dataset and I want an NA placeholder for that. My explanation mistake. Thank you!